# Change response url with Java HttpResponse

Tags: java, http, web, webserver, server

I'm developing a simple WebServer with Java 
(Using org.apache.http.HttpRequest and org.apache.http.HttpResponse).

I have an HTML page like this:

```
<form action="/upload" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
  <label for="datafile1">First File:</label>
   <input type="file" id="datafile1" name="datafile1" size="40"><br>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

On the Java Server i get the POST request, read the Multipart content and
fill up an HttpEntity as Response but the page loaded is (obviously) **"/upload"**

How can I tell the browser that the response url is something else?

I have tried:

```
response.setHeader("Location","/");
```

But with HTTP Status code 200 nothing happened
And with HTTP Status code 302 the browser make a new request, deleting the one I have returned.

Any ideas?

Comment: The form action is set to "/upload" so 
browser load page with url "/upload" and my content 
but I want to change the url to "/" without making a new request-response (that will change the content)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should send it with a 3XX status code usualy 302.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I have done it with 2 response object and returned one with
"Location" and status 302.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean that you initialized another new response object?
Or just did what @JEY said?